# Programmatic way to search a page for the user in a browser

Tags: search, browser

I am working on a search engine project that will point a user to a page from, say Google, and show them where their search terms are in the document.  Most of us search Google and know that sometimes you have to CTRL-F to find where that word appeared on the page (especially on long pages).  I know some browser plug-ins can help with this - but is there a way to wrap the page in a frame and do it (even if you don't control the site being displayed)?

If not, what browser plug-ins might you recommend that I could customize & brand so the user can accomplish this task?  I'm guessing you could also write a Kinitex plug-in or GreaseMonkey script - but I'd prefer to not go any route that a newbie user wouldn't immediately understand.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get source code of the page with curl, add javascript function to it and then pass result to the user. Just like server-side GreaseMonkey. :)

Comment: Yes - very clever.  But this isn't how Google works.  The site has to load directly from its owner.

Comment: There is no legimate way to perform javascript at the external page. At least i can't think about one. Can't suggest any plugin eather. :(

Answer (score 0):

In google Chrome try Google Quick Scroll,  it does it.